# How to access first User in an Array

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase

I'm trying to download user from Firebase and save them in an array using a Usermodel. 
The download works so far, but how do I access the first user and show the picture of this user?

My Usermodel: Sorry for some German words

```
class UserModel {

var username: String?
var email: String?
var profilImageUrl: String
var birthdayDate: String?
var gender: String?
var userDescription: String?


init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    username = dictionary["username"] as? String
    email = dictionary["email"] as? String
    profilImageUrl = dictionary["profilImageURL"] as? String ?? ""
    birthdayDate = dictionary["Geburtsdatum"] as? String
    gender = dictionary["gender"] as? String
    userDescription = dictionary["description"] as? String
}
```

In the following I´m saving the downloaded Data to the array "attendees".The picture of the first user in this array should be shown in firstUserImageView.

```
import SDWebImage
var attendees = [UserModel]()
@IBOutlet weak var firstUserImageView: UIImageView!
```

//load attendees with Api -> that works. 
print(attendees.count) gives me the amount of attendees saved in the database

```
func loadAttendees(){
    guard let eventID = event?.id else {return}

    AttendeeApi.shared.observeEventAttendee(eventID: eventID) { (attendeeId) in
        AttendeeApi.shared.observeAttendee(attendeeId: attendeeId, completion: { (attendee) in
            self.attendees.append(attendee)
        })
    }
}
```

Set up the image view

```
var attendee: UserModel?{
    didSet {
        let firstAttendee = attendees[0].profilImageUrl
        guard let firstUserImageUrl = URL(string: firstAttendee) else {return}
        firstUserImageView.sd_setImage(with: firstUserImageUrl) { (_, _, _, _) in
        }
    }
}
```

loadAttendees is called in viewDidLoad but the ImageView does not show the picture of the first user.

```
var REF_ATTENDEE = Database.database().reference().child("users")


func observeAttendee (attendeeId: String, completion: @escaping (UserModel) -> Void) {
    REF_ATTENDEE.child(attendeeId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {return}
        let newAttendee = UserModel(dictionary: dic)
        completion(newAttendee)
    }
}

var REF_EVENTS_ATTENDEES = Database.database().reference().child("events - attendees")

func observeEventAttendee(eventID: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    REF_EVENTS_ATTENDEES.child(eventID).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let attendeeId = snapshot.key
        completion(attendeeId)

    }
}
```

Comment: actually I dont care which user is shown. I just want to show one user out of all the users. These users are attendees of an event and I want to code something like: "picture of user" and 3 more are attending

Comment: Are you sure your URL string is valid? Does your code pass from URL guard?

Comment: I checked with a print commend. It doesn´t pass the URL guard. But I actually have no idea why. The snapshot I´m getting from observe attendee shows all the attendees with a valid URL

Comment: where is your `var attendee:` being set?

Comment: can you explain that to me @Galo Torres Sevilla? Maybe it is not set

Comment: you have a `didSet` observer for `attendee`, if it's not set somewhere that code will never be executed. Also, you have a `attendee` getting a completely different object from the array by doing `let firstAttendee = attendees[0].profilImageUrl` which doesn't really make much sense

Comment: do you get result of print(firstAttendee)?

Comment: Ok I guess attendee is not set because I also don´t get a result from print(firstAttendee). How can I set the attendee then?

Comment: I did edit my post. Thank you

Comment: How many users does `print(attendees.count)` print.

Comment: it counts to 3. And there are 3 attendees

Comment: don´t have enough reputations to chat

Comment: Did edit my post